# Dojo Stateful watch method firing before value is actually set

Tags: dojo, deferred, stateful

Using Dojo 1.6.1.

**Update:** Here a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E4EaM/1/

A form is created with some fields.

```
this.projectServiceidField = new dijit.form.TextBox({
    label: 'idField'
    , name: 'project_service_id'
    , required: true
    , type: 'hidden'
}).placeAt(this.domNode);

this.projectServiceEquipmentSourceAddress = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    name: 'source_address_id'
    , required: true
    , store: model.CustomerAddressesPairsView
    , searchAttr: "name"
    , style: "width: 40ex;"
});
```

The application needs to be notified when all the widget values have been set. To do this, a Deferred object is created with a Stateful watch on the widget's 'value property. The Deferred objects are all placed into a DeferredList. Once a widget's value has been initially set, the watch is removed and it's Deferred object resolved.

```
//loop 
w.deferred = new dojo.Deferred();
da.push(w.deferred);

// Watch the widget's value
w.initWatch = w.watch('value', function(property, oldValue, newValue) {
    w.initWatch.unwatch();
    console.debug(w.name, 'property:', property, 'oldValue:', oldValue,'newValue:', newValue,'w.get(\'value\'):', w.get('value'));
    w.deferred.resolve();
});

// Set the widget's value
w.set('value', value);

//endloop

var dl = new dojo.DeferredList(da);
```

When the DeferredList is resolved, all the widget values should have been set.

```
dl.then(
    function() {
        dojo.forEach(da, function(d) {
            console.debug(Date.now(), d);
        })

        console.debug(Date.now(), dl, 'DeferredList resolved -------->', form.getValues());
        console.debug(form.getValues());
    }
);
```

But, it doesn't work as expected. Specifically the fields that do xhr requests. Here are the values generated on the 'value' change events.

**project_service_id** property: **value** oldValue:  newValue: **1025** w.get('value'): **1025**

**source_address_id** property: **value** oldValue:  newValue: **59** w.get('value'):

source_address_id was supposed to have a value 59 but when I w.get('value'), it's not equal to  newValue. Shouldn't they be?

How can I determine when a widget's value has been set? Why isn't value == w.get('value')  immediately after w.set('value', value)?

If w.set('value', value) is not really setting the value, shouldn't it return a deferred?

Shouldn't watch only fire after the value has been set?

**Dojo Versions:**

Fails in Dojo 1.6.1. Watch doesn't always fire and w.get('value') != newValue when it does.

Fails less in Dojo 1.7.2. The watch still doesn't always fire but at least w.get('value') == newValue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after some discussion with richard on irc, we were able to figure out that there was some nuance between `dojox.data.QueryReadStore` and `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` that prevented the `"value"` watch callback being fired if the store hasn't already done a `fetch`.  the working solution was to do a `fetch` first and then create the widget in the `onComplete` callback - see http://jsfiddle.net/neonstalwart/dEC7M/

the relevant part is

```
customerAddressesPairsView.fetch({
    onComplete: function() {
        var w = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
            name: 'source_address_id',
            required: true,
            store: customerAddressesPairsView,
            searchAttr: "name",
            style: "width: 40ex;"
        }, 'sourceAddress');

        var handle = w.watch(function(property, oldValue, newValue) {
            console.log(property, oldValue, newValue);
        });

        w.set("value", value1);
        console.debug('Value set to ' + value1);
        console.debug('Immediate get returns:', w.get('value'));
        console.debug('Direct access returns: ' + w.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've made a small optimization to avoid downloading all the values. Instead of fetch, I'm doing a fetchItemByIdentity http://jsfiddle.net/rayotte/dh5pa/1/